# "point earner" problem: cousin of AM-GM

Tags: inequality, summation

Let $x(i) > 0$ for $i = 1,2,\cdots,2013$ and $x(1)\cdot x(2)\cdot \cdots \cdot x(2013) =1$ , prove:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2013}x(i)^{2013} \ge \sum_{i=1}^{2013}x(i)^{1/2013}
$$

Comment: This is false if all $x(i)$ are equal to $1$. Maybe you don't want strict inequality?

Comment: I just "edited" it by adding the equal sign. Thanks for noticing the error.

Comment: Type *\ge* for a fancier greater than or equal :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the GM is $1$, by Power Means Inequality

$$\sqrt[2013]{\frac1{2013}\sum_i x_i^{2013}} \ge 1 \ge\left(\frac1{2013}\sum_i \sqrt[2013]{x_i}\right)^{2013}$$

$$\implies \sum_i x_i^{2013} \ge 2013 \ge \sum_i \sqrt[2013]{x_i}$$

Comment: This is an interesting remark, but for me it feels like nuking a nut.

Comment: @chubakueno I find Power Means an easy extension of AM-GM-HM to remember and quite often useful. Maybe your experience has been different.

Comment: I agree, but it just gives away this problem. It is a valid and concise solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

Now that a full answer has been given, I will prove the generalisation:

$$x,y\in \mathbb{N},\prod^n_{i=1}a_i=1 \implies \sum^n_{i=1}a_i^x \ge \sum^n_{i=1}\sqrt[y]{a_i}$$
By $\text{AM}\ge \text{GM}$
$$\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{xy-1 \text{ times}}+a_i^x\ge xy\sqrt[y]{a_i}$$
Summing up for all $a_i$
$$\implies n(xy-1) +\sum^n_{i=1}a_i^x\ge xy\sum^n_{i=1}\sqrt[y]{a_i}$$

If $xy=1$, we are done. If not, we also have:

$$\sum^n_{i=1}\sqrt[y]{a_i}\ge n \implies xy\sum^n_{i=1}\sqrt[y]{a_i}-n(xy-1)\ge \sum^n_{i=1}\sqrt[y]{a_i}$$
Done! Now put $x=y=n=2013$.